# Making a sub-section in an option of a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm currently making a plugin. I have many options and want to know if it would be possible to make a sub-section for an option in an jquery plugin.

Like this:

```
$('#id').name({
    extra: {
        more: ''
    }
});
```

I really don't know if its possible. But if it is I would also need to know how to retrieve the information in `more` for example.

Comment: Yes? `options.extra.more.ladida`?

Comment: It would more have to be: options.extra.more

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: Yup. I just found out how to do it. So how about you answer with my answer and I can up it. And click the Check. ;)

Comment: You do realize you can answer and accept your own answers, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set them just how you have it set up. To retrieve the options, simply use `options.extra.more`.

If you do this:

```
$('#id').name({
    extra: {
        more: {
            evenMore: ''
        }
    }
});
```

You can use `options.extra.more.evenMore` to retrieve it, and so on.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvfsQ/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            return $(this).each(function(){
                console.log(settings.extra.more);

            });
        }
    };
    var settings = {};

    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
        methods.init();
    };
})(jQuery);

$('input').test({
    extra: {
        more: 'la-di-da'
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuB7t/

Comment: And I'm guessing the -1 is for...?

Comment: I am supposing I was -1 from @Shawn31313 for some reason, irrespective of the answer I provided (which was -1 shortly after the accepted answer was +1)?

Comment: Your awnser just did not help me. And what is that jsfiddle suppose to do?

Comment: Aha. And you didnt tell me how to retrieve the information from `more`. So You still got a -1.

Comment: Line 5: `console.log(settings.extra.more);`.